# Why do some formulas for statistical power not take into account variance?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, statistical-power

I just read [this](http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/bs704_power/BS704_Power_print.html) article on power analysis. I want to figure out the size of a sample needed to detect a 1% change in proportions for independent samples with a dichotomous outcome (see "Sample Sizes for Two Independent Samples, Dichotomous Outcomes" in the article for a quick description).

The formula for sample size, oddly enough, does not take into account the variance of the underlying distribution (just the z-statistics and the effect size, which is just a function of the proportions).

[image: sample size formula]

**How does this make sense?** Surely power is also a function of variance (high variance should decrease power because it's harder to detect a signal through the noise). Can someone explain why the formula for sample size doesn't explicitly account for underlying variance?

Comment: The Z statistic is already normalized by the standard deviation,  So the variance for the original variable is accounted for.

Comment: Effect size is also usually normalized. ... by casting things related to the original measurement scale entirely in terms of standardized quantities, it accounts for variance.

Comment: @MichaelChernick I'm a bit confused. I thought Z-statistics were determined by looking at the standard normal distribution, meaning that  Z_{1-alpha/2} = Z_{0.975} = 1.96 always. It seems from your answer that this is not the case. Can you help clarify my confusion?

Comment: Yes but you get there by dividing by the assumed standard deviation.

Comment: @MicaelChernick Sorry, I don't understand. Given the underlying distribution with mean mu and std sigma, how do I calculate a Z statistic?

Comment: The answer is in the middle of the [article](http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/bs704_power/BS704_Power_print.html). [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTS7Q.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTS7Q.jpg)

Comment: You have not quoted the formula posted in the section you reference.  This formula comes from a different section entirely.

Answer (score 2):

The "effect size" (ES) as defined in the [linked web page](http://sphweb.bumc.bu.edu/otlt/mph-modules/bs/bs704_power/BS704_Power_print.html)* and used in its formulas for power calculations includes the variance. In general, the ES as defined there is the ratio of the magnitude of the difference you wish to detect divided by a standard deviation.

For the Bernoulli trials involved in distinguishing differences in proportions, the variance is fixed by the proportion of successes $p$ at $p(1-p)$. The ES then is $|p_2-p_1|/\sqrt{p(1-p)}$, where $(p_2-p_1)$ is the difference in probabilities you wish to distinguish and $p$ is a pooled estimate of overall probability.

---

*There are many related definitions of [effect size](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effect_size), so use caution when you come upon the term in general.